# symfony - Embed a Collection of Forms

Tags: symfony

is there anyway to do [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype) example without javascript ?
I want to embed 5 forms, so there's no need to let the user to add forms.
thanks.

Comment: If you don't need to allow user to add extra elements (forms) to the collection, just follow what you find in the cookbook that you linked and don't use `allow_add`, `allow_delete` and javascript sections

Comment: I want to `allow_add`, but `allow_add` only 5 forms.

Comment: The question isn't clear: if you want to block up to 5 forms (added by javascript) you need to modify javascript itself and perform also server side controls. If you need to take five forms that are already created (so basically you're not allowing user to add more from that collection), well, you just need to follow what I've suggested above